# Is it possible to build modular pages in Bolt CMS 4? Similar to GravCMS modular pages or SuluCMS content blocks

Tags: bolt-cms

I can't find it in the documentation, but maybe someone did it?

GravCMS - modular pages: https://learn.getgrav.org/17/content/modular
SuluCMS - content blocks: https://docs.sulu.io/en/2.3/book/templates.html#content-blocks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, you are looking for the Collection field: https://docs.bolt.cm/4.0/fields/collection

Comment: But you need a new type of content each time. And it doesn't allow you to create and use the same block multiple times on different pages.

Comment: If you want to define content once and reuse it for different content types, you can use YAML Repeated Nodes: https://docs.bolt.cm/4.0/contenttypes/intro#advanced-yaml-repeated-nodes

Comment: This is actually closer to what I would like to achieve. Thank you for your replay :)